# Setting Future Date in SF using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hello stackexchange gurus.

I have a problem with setting a future Due Date for a task using javascript in Salesforce. Below is the piece of code i use:

```
var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
    var date =(d.getDate()+"/"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getFullYear()).dateFormat;
    taskToCreate.ActivityDate = date;
```

Unfortunately, the result of this code is empty "Due Date" field. In case i get rid of `.dateFormat`, the error will appear, saying something like "incorrect value format for required field".

In case there is a simplier solution for setting Due Date as "7 days from today's date", i'd be grateful if you share your knowledge.

I was unable to find the answer on my own, and i will really appreciate any advice on that issue.

Thank you in advance,
Best Regards.

Comment: I'm not a specialist of javascript, but is it normal to have quote on the last line ?

Comment: Hi Yann G. That was an old bit of code, the one i'm using in SF is without quotes (but still with the same result). Thanks fo noticing that, will change it in the main message.

Comment: Have you tried to format this date format : var date =d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1)+ "-" + d.getDate();

Comment: When i manually add a date to a field, the date separator is "/" (also thats how the date is presented in SF, e.g. 23/01/2015). I also tried to switch places of month/day (UK and US version), but that wasnt the case, got the same result..

Comment: what is '.dateformat'? Where did that come from?

Comment: Well as i understood this is a method to convert a string to date format. Without it, an error occures, saying that "1/23/2015" is not a valid format for date field (the problem is in 0 in front of "01", i guess).

Comment: check out the solution for this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17644/javascript-date-on-custom-button-issue.. You can use `sforce.internal.dateTimeToString(new Date())` function to the work done.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the issue by changing the code to this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
var date1 =((d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getFullYear());
taskToCreate.ActivityDate = new Date(date1);
```

Thanks everybody who spent their time to go through the question!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Q&A. I needed to assign these dates to custom fields so here is my solution. Now these variables are eligible to be used in component.set()

```
    var d = new Date();
    console.log('dday');
    var today =$A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(today);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
    var nextweek = $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date((d.getMonth()+1)+"/"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getFullYear()), "YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(nextweek);
```